# Django Carousel with pictures choosen by admin in front-end from a list

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to set in my `django` web application a `Bootstrap` or `Javascript carousel` a bit particular. Up to now and as I see, carousel pictures are defined inside the backend code by developer.

I would like to make a carousel where pictures are defined by admin from a template with a choice list of publications.

Each publication has a cover page. So admin user could check one or multiple publication and the carousel placed in an other template loads previous selected pictures.

I have different questions from this idea :

- How I can save admin choice in order to use checked picture in the carousel ? (Maybe through database but how ?)
- How I can pass variables check from a class view to another one ? (I have to set global variables ?)
- Do you have any idea if something like that already exists ?

Thank you so much by advance for any idea !

I have my model file :

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    new_publication = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('new publication'), default=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', verbose_name=_('cover page'), default='')
```

I have in my view, this class :

```
class HomeView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['publication_list_newest'] = Publication.objects.filter(new_publication=True).order_by('pub_id')
        return super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

And in my template, I'm trying to set something like this :

```
<div class="row">
      <h3>{% trans 'Newest publications' %}</h3>
      <hr>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          {% for publication in publication_list_newest %}
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{ publication.id }}" class="active"></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="la.jpg" alt="Cover page" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
          {% for publication in publication_list_newest %}
            <div class="item">
              <img src="{{ publication.cover.url }}" alt="{{ publication.cover }}" style="width:100%;">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>{{ publication.title }} ({{ publication.pub_id }})</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Through this way, pictures are displayed automatically because it takes account the attribut `new_publication`. But user has to get the possibility to chose himself, which publication will be display in the carousel.

Comment: Start by defining your models (for example a `Publication` with a cover image and a `Page` with a `publication_carousel`), write some code for them and add them to the Django admin and then come back with a more specific question. Right now your question is too broad.

Comment: I will edit my question ;)

Comment: You could do two things: 1. Add a field to `Publication`, like `is_featured` so the admin can mark which publications to show on your home page. You then just need to filter on this field. Probably your best option if that's the only place on your website you'd do this 2. Create a new model `FeaturedSection` with a ManyToMany relationship to `Publication` and maybe an additional property `placement` with choices that determines where the section is placed. Then you add the `FeaturedSection` with `placement="home"` to the context of your home page and display its `publications`.

Comment: If you also need to order the publications manually in the admin, you might want to look at a 3rd party package like django-admin-sortable, django-admin-sortable2 or django-ordered-model.

Comment: @dirkgroten It's exactly what I'm doing for. I created a new publication field `in_carousel` and in my page `Manage Carousel`, I display a table with all publications and checkboxes. When I submit the table with publications checked, I turn the new boolean field in `True` and the carousel will show all publications with `in_carousel = True`. For the sort, I'll look your comment !